# Fetching values from string

Tags: java, string

I have string `{"AAA":xxxxx,"BB":xxxx,"CCC":"3 xxx"}`, and I want to get the values of `AAA` , `BB` and `CCC` as my output.I am using `substring` method of string i am able to get only `AAA`

```
metaDataValue = mettaDataValue.substring(metaDataValue.indexOf("")+1,metaDataValue.indexOf(":"));
```

Comment: Have you considered using [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))?

Comment: is this a json string?? If it is JSON then use JSON parser

Comment: AAA , BB , CC capture in my string, i am getting StringIndexOutOFBoundException when using while to traverse the string.

Comment: my string is store in this format {"AAA":xxxxx,"BB":xxxx,"CCC":"3 xxx"},

Comment: So your String s="{"AAA":xxxx,"BB":xxx,"CCC":"3 xxx"}" is that so??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a well-formed string, **with no commas in the key and the value**, a very simple solution can be:

```
String str = ...
str = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);     // removing the {}
String[] entries = str.split(",");            // get all the "key":value
for (String entry: entries) {
   String[] entryData = entry.split(":");     // get the key and the value
   String key = entryData[0];
   key = key.substring(1, key.length() - 1);  // removing the "" from key
   String value = entryData[1];
   System.out.println(key + " -> " + value);
}
```

You can test here: http://ideone.com/weEbt2

If you want to have commas in keys or values, I think you have to make a little parser.

Comment: public void processString(String line)
 {
    
  metaDataValue = metaDataValue.substring(metaDataValue.indexOf("{")+1, metaDataValue.indexOf("}"));
  
   String [] splitMetaDataValue =  metaDataValue.split(",");
   String [] tokenValue = null;
    for (int i = 0; i<splitMetaDataValue.length ; i++)
    {
     tokenValue = splitMetaDataValue[i].split(":");
     System.out.println("Token Heads"+tokenValue[0]);
    }
   
 }//processString
input String {"AAA":xxxx,"AAAB:xxxx,"AAAA":xxxx,}
Token Heads"AAA"
Token Heads"AAAB"

Answer (score 2):

If it is JSON use parser.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.getString("AAA");
```

Comment: there is no JSON its just string in java

Comment: JSON is the format of the string - you parse the string into a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**`Json Parser`**](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Add the [**`jar`**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm) to your project

json:   `{"AAA":xxxxx,"BB":xxxx,"CCC":"3 xxx"}`

Do like this to get the string in java

```
    JSONObject json=new JSONObject(string);
    String A=json.getString("AAA");
    String B=json.getString("BBB");
    String C=json.getString("CCC");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create class that contains properties AAA, BB and CCC

```
public class OutputResult {

    private String AAA;
    private String BB;
    private String CCC;

    // Getters and setters ...
```

And then read that object from json string, using for example [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
OutputResult outputResult = mapper.readValue(jsonString, OutputResult.class);
```

Comment: can u tell me how can i traverse in string??

Comment: First you can split string with str.split(","). Then you have array of expressions like this: "AAA":xxxx. Then you can split strings again with substring.split(":")

Answer (score 0):

If your using only java,

you can use this.

```
    String str= "{\"AAA\":xxxxx,\"BB\":xxxx,\"CCC\":\"3 xxx\"}";
    String st[] = str.split("\"");
    for(int i=1;i<st.length-2;i+=2){
        System.out.println(st[i]);
    }
```